# What happen to the iterators if you erase() an element in C++?

Tags: c++

I was trying to implementing a C++ method that removes leading and trailing spaces

```
    string::iterator begin = s.begin();
    string::iterator end = s.end()-1;
    while (*begin == ' ') {
        cout << "*begin is: " << *begin << endl;
        begin++;
    }
    while (*end == ' ') {
        cout << "*end is: " << *end << endl;
        end--;
    }
    s.erase(s.begin(),begin);
    s.erase(end+1,s.end());
```

Then my code CRASHED. After several debugging, I found that it was actually caused my some sort of "iterator mis-location" (I made this name up...don't know what's exactly this error called...) when I `erase()` elements from string. So if I do this instead (change the procedure):

```
    string::iterator begin = s.begin();
    while (*begin == ' ') {
        cout << "*begin is: " << *begin << endl;
        begin++;
    }
    s.erase(s.begin(),begin);


    string::iterator end = s.end()-1;
    while (*end == ' ') {
        cout << "*end is: " << *end << endl;
        end--;
    }
    s.erase(end+1,s.end());
```

no more problems :D

So I really would like to know what's exactly happening to the iterator when you `erase()` element from it. For example, if you `erase()` first/last two elements, what's gonna happen to `s.end()`/`s.begin()`?

Comment: I believe the term you're looking for is iterator invalidation.

Comment: When you erase any existing iterators are invalidated, just like it says in the description of the erase. So in order for you to erase from both start and end you would need to split it up in two passes where you first erase the starting spaces then get new iterators to erase the trailing ones.

Comment: Instrad of using manual loops, look at the [`find_first_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of) and [`find_last_not_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_not_of) methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirements on `std::string` say: (§[string.require]/4):

> References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that basic_string object:
>   [...]
>   — Calling non-const member functions, except operator[], at, front, back, begin, rbegin, end, and rend.

I'd just use `substr`, something like this:

```
s = s.substr(begin, end-begin);
```

I'd probably also use string's member functions to do the searching:

```
auto begin = s.find_first_not_of(' ');
auto end = s.find_last_not_of(' ');
s = s.substr(begin, end-begin);
```

Since it does the job in a single operation, it avoids any problems with iterator invalidation (and as a bonus, it may be a bit faster).

Comment: The standard can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

Comment: Thank you Jerry, this is a really handy and clean solution.